# exam class with exercises and points in range

Tags: exam

I use the exam class for writing my exam [ctan exam](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam)

The problem regards the counting of points when you have several exercises (so several question environments)

Normally you have solutions in the exam class but I may use this options in a wrong way.

You can find below a basic example which didn't work... exercices have same points and gradingtable.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}                                                   
%\printanswers % pour imprimer les réponses (corrigé)
\noprintanswers % Pour ne pas imprimer les réponses (énoncé)
\addpoints % Pour compter les points
\pointsinrightmargin % Pour avoir les points dans la marge à droite
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Exercice 1 : \pointsinrange{ex1} pts}

\begin{questions}
  \begingradingrange{ex1}
  \question[1] question1
  \question[2] question2
  \question 
  \begin{parts}
    \part[1] question3a
    \part[2] question3.b
   \end{parts}
   \endgradingrange{ex1}
\end{questions}

\partialgradetable{ex1}[h][questions]

\textbf{Exercice 2 : \pointsinrange{ex2} pts}

\begin{questions}
  \begingradingrange{ex2}
  \question[2] question1
  \question[1] question2
  \question 
  \begin{parts}
    \part[2] question3a
    \part[3] question3.b
  \end{parts}
  \endgradingrange{ex2}
\end{questions}

\partialgradetable{ex2}[h][questions]

\end{document}
```

**The problem is that each exercise has the same points attributed to it and grading table whereas there are different affectations for questions...**

[image: pdf capture of problem]

*(I have just merge my 2 accounts)*

The grading table for exercise 1 should be :

[image: normal grading table for ex1]

Thank you in advance ;)

Benoit

Comment: If you look the first grading table it is the points of exercice two normally with affectation the first grading table should be :
Question 1 2 3 Total
Points   1 2 3 6

Comment: This has also been posted at [LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=25280&view=unread#p86036).

Comment: @Johannes_B do I have to delete from LaTeX-community ?

Comment: I'm not sure you should have multiple `question` environments in one document with `exam` class - it does not seem to support more than one.  Could you put each exercise in a separate document?  Or perhaps just have a single `question` environment so that the question numbers continue across each "exercise".

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: @Thruston effectively it is impossible examdoc p 36 : "If you do have more than one questions environment, though, you won’t be able to use the \gradetable or \pointtable commands (see section 9)."

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the answer provided by the OP, but allows for multiple questions to appear in each `\partialgradetable`. The problem was having multiple question environments. The tables are correct if you have multiple grading ranges between one set of `\begin{questions}` and `\end{questions}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}                                                   
%\printanswers % pour imprimer les réponses (corrigé)
\noprintanswers % Pour ne pas imprimer les réponses (énoncé)
\addpoints % Pour compter les points
\pointsinrightmargin % Pour avoir les points dans la marge à droite
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\uplevel{\textbf{Exercise 1 : \pointsinrange{ex1} pts}}
\begingradingrange{ex1}
  \question[1] question1
  \question[2] question2
  \question 
  \begin{parts}
    \part[1] question3a
    \part[2] question3.b
   \end{parts}
\endgradingrange{ex1}

\partialgradetable{ex1}[h][questions]

\uplevel{\textbf{Exercise 2 : \pointsinrange{ex2} pts}}
\begingradingrange{ex2}
  \question[2] question1
  \question[1] question2
  \question 
  \begin{parts}
    \part[2] question3a
    \part[3] question3.b
  \end{parts}
\endgradingrange{ex2}
\end{questions}
\partialgradetable{ex2}[h][questions]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have just compiled your version and the gradingtable are the same for both exercises...

Comment: @BenoitLandrieu Restarting the question numbering with `\setcounter{question}{0}` caused both grading tables to be the same. I've removed that command from my answer, and it should compile correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{exam}                                                   
%\printanswers % pour imprimer les réponses (corrigé)
\noprintanswers % Pour ne pas imprimer les réponses (énoncé)
\addpoints % Pour compter les points
\pointsinrightmargin % Pour avoir les points dans la marge à droite
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%-----------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\thesubpart}{\alph{subpart}}
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\arabic{partno}}
\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\textbf{Exercice \thequestion:}}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\thepartno.}
\renewcommand{\subpartlabel}{(\thesubpart)}
%-----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \begingradingrange{ex1}
  \question \pointsinrange{ex1} pts
  \begin{parts}
    \part[1] question1
    \part[2] question2
    \part
    \begin{subparts}
      \subpart[1] question3a
      \subpart[2] question3.b
    \end{subparts}
  \end{parts}
  \endgradingrange{ex1}

  \partialgradetable{ex1}[h][questions]

  \begingradingrange{ex2}
  \question \pointsinrange{ex2} pts
  \begin{parts}
    \part[2] question1
    \part[2] question2
    \part
    \begin{subparts}
      \subpart[2] question3a
      \subpart[1] question3.b
      \subpart[2] question3.c
    \end{subparts}
  \end{parts}
  \endgradingrange{ex2}

  \partialgradetable{ex2}[h][questions]

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to touhami from http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/class-exam-avec-exercices-gestions-points-range-t16068.html

Benoit

Comment: I found a very similar method, but it allows you to have more than one entry in the `\partialgradetable`. Also, you don't have to change the appearance of all the parts and subparts. Please see my answer for details.

Comment: Can you post the solution to LaTeX-community as well? Please also inform @touhami about crossposting. This is showing respect to the fellow users. Thanks.