# Multiple Exams in One File

Tags: exam

I need to create an exam which consists of two parts A and B. From these two parts, I need to create three versions: one which contains part A and B, one which only contains part A and one which only contains part B. Each version needs to have a custom title page, its own page and question numbering, and a point table.

What I would like to have in the end is a single PDF file of the following structure:

- title page for A + B (page no. 1)
- questions from A numbered 1 to n
- questions from B numbered n + 1 to m
- title page for A (restart page and question numbering, set point sum back to 0)
- questions from A numbered 1 to n
- title page for B (restart page and question numbering, set point sum back to 0)
- questions from B numbered 1 to m

Currently, I use the following approach: one file contains the questions from A; one file contains those from B. A master file includes these files and uses custom counters to restart the page/question numbering when appropriate. This works okay but it would be nice if I could use some of the features in the `exam` class (e.g. optionally show solutions, boxes for the answers relative to the page height). I am aware that these features can be implemented manually but this is time consuming and the result is probably less user-friendly than using a well-maintained, well-documented external package/class.

This, finally, brings me to my question: can this be achieved using the exam class (especially, having multiple point sums in one file) or a different package?

**Edit**: Using the answers from the question which is linked in the comments I was able to get pretty close to what I need. I now have three file:

`a.tex`:

```
\question A's first question
\begin{parts}
  \part[1] part 1
  \part[2] part 2
  \part 
  \begin{subparts}
    \subpart[1] 3a
    \subpart[2] 3b
  \end{subparts}
\end{parts}

\question[2] A's second question
```

`b.tex`:

```
\question B's first question
\begin{parts}
  \part[2] part b1
  \part[2] part b2
\end{parts}

\question[1] B's second question
\question[2] B's third question
```

`main.tex`:

```
    \documentclass[a5paper, addpoints]{exam}

\pointsinrightmargin

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}  
  \begin{questions}
    \begingradingrange{AB}
      \uplevel{
        % Title page for A + B
        \partialgradetable{AB}[h][questions]
      }

      \input{a.tex}
      \input{b.tex}
    \endgradingrange{AB}
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \begingradingrange{onlyA}
      \uplevel{
        % Title page for A
        \partialgradetable{onlyA}[h][questions]
      }
      \input{a.tex}
    \endgradingrange{onlyA}
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \begingradingrange{onlyB}
      \uplevel{
        % Title page for B
        \partialgradetable{onlyB}[h][questions]
      }
      \input{b.tex}
    \endgradingrange{onlyB}
    \clearpage
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Compiling `main.tex` creates three pages:

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

[image: page 3]

The first page is exactly how I want it to be. The question numbering - especially, in the grade table - on the second and third page, however, has to start with question 1 again.

I hope that this clarifies my question.

Comment: A lot of requests for not providing a MWE to start with ;-)

Comment: Since A and B are completely independant, wouldn't it be much easier to simply merge the resulting pdfs?

Comment: @Johannes_B I don't tink so since he needs a sum of points

Comment: see here it maybe helpful http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209504/exam-class-with-exercises-and-points-in-range

Comment: @touhami is that you? ;-) http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/inclure-des-images-avec-xelatex-et-a0poster-t16198.html

Comment: @Johannes_B yes i am

Comment: @touhami Your link is very close to what I need. But there must be a way to reset the question numbering.

Comment: @JPW the second answer there doesn't do this? if not you shoud give a minimal code of what you have and what youneed.

Comment: @JPW Could it be possible to achieve what you want using the [`combine` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine)? Make sure to use the workaround given in the doc (p.5) of `combine` to make it work together with `exam`.

Comment: @touhami No it doesn't. With the answer by Benoit Landrieu, each grade table contains only a single question and the second table starts with number 2. With erik's answer, the numbering in the second table likewise starts with 4. Adding a ``\setcounter{question}{0}```breaks everything, as stated in the comments to the answer.

Comment: @JPW I will try to do some thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[a5paper, addpoints]{exam}

\pointsinrightmargin

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%---------------------------------------------------
\newcounter{mtexo}
\newcommand{\setpart}{%
\setcounter{page}{1}\setcounter{mtexo}{0}%
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\themtexo}}
%---------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}  
  \begin{questions}
%---------------------------------------------------
\let\mtquestion\question
\def\question{\refstepcounter{mtexo}\mtquestion}
%---------------------------------------------------
    \begingradingrange{AB}
      \uplevel{
        % Title page for A + B
        \partialgradetable{AB}[h][questions]
      }

      \input{a.tex}
      \input{b.tex}
    \endgradingrange{AB}
    \clearpage
    \setpart%\setcounter{page}{1}

    \begingradingrange{onlyA}
      \uplevel{
        % Title page for A
        \partialgradetable{onlyA}[h][questions]
      }
      \input{a.tex}
    \endgradingrange{onlyA}
    \clearpage
    \setpart%\setcounter{page}{1}

    \begingradingrange{onlyB}
      \uplevel{
        % Title page for B
        \partialgradetable{onlyB}[h][questions]
      }
      \input{b.tex}
    \endgradingrange{onlyB}
    \clearpage
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

you can add the \clearpage command to \setpart

Comment: Redefining ``\thequestion`` indeed seems to do the trick. Thank you very much!