# Which package can be used to create a Question-Bank containing many question papers?

Tags: exam, books, questionnaire

While creating a Question Bank, I need the following options,

- Use external files to populate the Question Bank.
  (i.e. combine multiple `QP0#.tex` files into `QB-All.tex` by using `\import{QP0#.tex}`).
- Use `\printanswers` to show answers in some parts and hide answers in other parts.
- Add marks and print the Question-Wise "Table of Marks" for each Question-Paper.
- Whole Bank should have continuous page numbers.

---

I have been using the `exam` package to create individual question papers.

#### Contents of `QP-0#.tex` (QP01.tex, QP02.tex, QP03.tex,...):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
    \gradetable[questions]
    \begin{questions}
        \question[2] Question 01
        \begin{solutionorlines}[5cm]
            Solution
        \end{solutionorlines}

        \question[5] Question nn
        \begin{solutionorlines}[5cm]
            Solution
        \end{solutionorlines}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

#### Contents of `QB-All.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{intro.tex}

\chapter{Polynomials}
\input{intro.tex}
.
.
.
\chapter{Linear Equations}
\input{linearEquations.tex}

\chapter{Question Papers-Assignments}
Text Content of few paragraphs

\section{Question Paper - 2019}
\input{QP19.tex}

\section{Question Paper - 2020}
\input{QP20.tex}
.
.
.
\section{Question Paper - 2023}
\printanswers
\input{QP23.tex}


\chapter{Question Papers-Answers}
Text Content of few paragraphs

\section{Question Paper - 2019}
\printanswers
\input{QP19.tex}

\section{Question Paper - 2020}
\printanswers
\input{QP20.tex}
.
.
.
\section{Question Paper - 2023}
\printanswers
\input{QP23.tex}

\end{document}
```

---

Currently the `exam` class doesn't support multiple `questions` environment. So I am generating PDFs of each Question Paper separately and manually combining the generated PDFs using `pdftk`. But this leads to page numbering issues and incomplete table of contents.

##### Resources Tried:

- [exam-class-with-exercises-and-points-in-range](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209504/exam-class-with-exercises-and-points-in-range/209533#209533)
- [how-to-create-book-with-multiple-exam-question-papers-in-chapters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238863/how-to-create-book-with-multiple-exam-question-papers-in-chapters)
- [multiple-exams-in-one-file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231634/multiple-exams-in-one-file)

Comment: There is two packages called `ex_test` and `ex_test_rd`  provide multiple question and everything that you expected. However, these are written by a Vietnamese and are not published so there are not manual in English. If possible you can read the .sty files here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1D-zJ8wCW-U4G827TZAdX7-xh8cl_tN1s?usp=sharing.